# index.html:507 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I tried searching but i cannot find anything that helps answer my questions. Im trying to send form data into JSON format. While also doing a console.log to see how the JSON is output and will be set to the server.

Below is my code. Thanks for any help!

```
 <form enctype='application/json' style="text-align: center" method="post" name="form">
                                <input name="firstname" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"> &nbsp
                                <input name="lastname" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"> &nbsp
                                <input name="email" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> &nbsp
                                <select name="category" value="" class="form-control">
                                    <option selected disabled value="choose">--Category--</option>
                                    <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
                                    <option value="books">Books</option>
                                    <option value="music">Music</option>
                                </select> &nbsp
                                <input name="itemName" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name"> &nbsp
                                <input name="itemDesc" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Description"> &nbsp
                                <input name="priceInput" value="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Price ($00.00)"> &nbsp

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button name="submit" value="" onclick ="onsubmit()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            </form>


             <script>
                            var form;

                            form.onsubmit = function (e) {
                                //stop regular form submission
                                e.preventDefault();

                                //collect the form data 
                                var data = {};
                                for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i <ii; ++i) {
                                    var input = form[i];
                                    if (input.name) {
                                        data[input.name] = input.value;
                                    }
                                }

                                //construct an HTTP request
                                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

                                //send the collected data as JSON
                                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

                                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                                xhr.onloadend = function () {
                                    //done
                                };
                            };

            </script>
```

Comment: You declare the variable `form` but you don't initialize it.

Comment: Im receiving the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of undefined in Google Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Right, because in the statement `form.onsubmit = ...` the value of the variable `form` is `undefined`. That's precisely what that error is telling you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
var form;
form <-- currently is undefined
form.onsubmit === undefined.onsubmit
```

You can use the `onsubmit` function on elements in your DOM. In order to do that you need to set the `form` variable to reference the `<form>` element in your code.

You can use

```
var form = document.forms['form']
```

The usage of 'form' here is because your `<form>` tag has `name="form"`.